# Error: Could not find module `ember-data/-private` imported from `ember-data/setup-container`

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

After my last build of the app everything was ok, but two days ago I've uploaded the new version of the app and this error is blocking me to launch the app on the dev environment.

Error: Could not find module `ember-data/-private` imported from `ember-data/setup-container`

I am not quite sure where to look or how to investigate the problem, please do let me know if I can provide with any extra info.

rgds

After upgrading ember-data, this is the log:

```
-----> emberjs app detected
-----> Setting NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION to false to install ember-cli toolchain
-----> Fetching buildpack heroku/nodejs-v98
-----> Node.js detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  >= 0.10.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version >= 0.10.0 via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing node 8.4.0...
       Using default npm version: 5.3.0
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       added 94 packages, removed 64 packages, updated 128 packages and moved 1 package in 20.502s
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Fetching buildpack heroku/ember-cli-deploy
-----> ember-cli detected
-----> Restoring bower cache
-----> Restoring bower cache
-----> Installing bower dependencies
-----> Caching bower cache
-----> Building ember assets
WARNING: Node v8.4.0 has currently not been tested against Ember CLI and may result in unexpected behaviour.
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
broccoli-babel-transpiler is opting out of caching due to a plugin that does not provide a caching strategy: `function () {
            return __dirname;
          }`.
Build failed.
File: ember-ajax/ajax-request.js
The Broccoli Plugin: [broccoli-persistent-filter:Babel] failed with:
TypeError: The plugin {"_parallelBabel":{"requireFile":"/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile/lib/require-from-worker","buildUsing":"build","params":{"templateCompilerPath":"/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler","parallelConfig":[]}}} didn't export a Plugin instance
    at PluginManager.validate (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/plugin-manager.js:164:13)
    at PluginManager.add (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/plugin-manager.js:213:10)
    at File.buildTransformers (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:237:21)
    atError running: ember build --environment production 2>&1
 new File (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:139:10)
    at Pipeline.transform (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:164:16)
    at Babel.transform (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:107:21)
    at Babel.processString (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:206:25)
    at Promise.then.result.output (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/lib/strategies/persistent.js:41:23)
    at initializePromise (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:589:5)
    at new Promise$1 (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1077:33)
The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
    at Babel.Plugin (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:7:31)
    at Babel.Filter [as constructor] (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/index.js:62:10)
    at new Babel (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:35:10)
    at EmberApp._addonTree (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:910:29)
    at EmberApp._processedVendorTree (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:944:20)
    at EmberApp._processedExternalTree (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:975:21)
    at EmberApp.appAndDependencies (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1071:30)
    at EmberApp.javascript (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1201:34)
    at EmberApp.toArray (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1606:10)
    at EmberApp.toTree (/tmp/build_94c194f54986baa49826d9ec451f3d9c/nalla-design-nalla-site-7aba2cfe5b751fec7f9b091d42b7de840218687d/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1628:30)
-----> Failed trying to compile heroku/ember-cli-deploy
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile emberjs app.
 !     Push failed
```

Dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
"broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.2",
"ember-ajax": "^2.0.1",
"ember-cli": "2.8.0",
"ember-cli-active-link-wrapper": "0.3.2",
"ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
"ember-cli-autoprefixer": "0.6.0",
"ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.6",
"ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
"ember-cli-fastboot": "1.0.0-beta.12",
"ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.3",
"ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
"ember-cli-jshint": "^1.0.0",
"ember-cli-qunit": "^2.1.0",
"ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
"ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
"ember-cli-stylus": "^1.0.6",
"ember-cli-swiper": "0.3.1",
"ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.0",
"ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
"ember-data": "^2.14.2",
"ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.5",
"ember-font-awesome": "2.2.0",
"ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
"ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
"ember-welcome-page": "^1.0.1",
"ember-windoc": "0.1.8",
"liquid-fire": "0.26.4",
"loader.js": "^4.0.1"
```

Comment: provide dependency versions for the following, please: ember, ember-cli, node, npm, ember-ajax, broccoli-persistent-filer

Comment: Just added it int he post Pavol

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a guessing but I faced something similar few days ago and found solution here:
ember-data issue: [Could not find module `ember-data/-private](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/5021)

Increasing Ember-data dependency solved my problem.

```
npm install --save ember-data@2.14.2
```

Comment: Thanks Pavol for the hint, sadly it didn't work
I just added the log into the post, any ideas?

Comment: Apparently the v2.15.0 release of Ember Data has a similar issue (https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/5163). According to the issue author locking Ember Data to v2.14.10 fixes the problem.

Comment: @roughprada have you tried to clean cache, too? `npm cache clean`

Comment: @Pavol I am now in ember-data 2.14.10, forced cleaned the cache and still have the same issue